# Function within angular directive that I can call from the controller

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create a function within a directive that can be called from the controller. It should look something like this:

HTML:

```
<div myDir id='myDir'>My dir</div>
<button ng-click="clickme()">click me</button>
```

JS:

```
app.directive("myDir", function(){
  return function(){
    var dirFunction = function(){
        alert("hello world");
    }
  }
}

app.controller("Control", function($scope){
   $scope.clickme = function(){
     angular.element('#myDir').dirFunction();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly in your HTML change `myDir` to `my-dir`. In your case you dont need to give an `id` to your div:

```
<div my-dir>My dir</div>
<button ng-click="clickme()">click me</button>
```

Now expose `dirFunction` to the scope. This would make it possible for your controller to access this function:

```
app.directive("myDir", function(){
    return function(scope){    
        scope.dirFunction = function(){
            alert("hello world");
        }
    }
});
```

And from within your controller just call it as `$scope.dirFunction()`:

```
app.controller("Control", function($scope){
    $scope.clickme = function(){
        $scope.dirFunction();
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** You should not do DOM manipulation inside your controller: `angular.element('#myDir').dirFunction();` in controller is a bad way to code in angularjs. Save this for the directive.

Comment: I want to call angular.element('#myDir').dirFunction() because I don't want to fire the function on all the directives at the same time, which would be the case if I called $scope.dirFunction. Is there a way of selecting which directive to call the function on?

Comment: actually thinking about it, I suppose I could do scope[attrs.comboName].dirFunction() = function(){...} - I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this with a solution: Here's the Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/m2YKLGGLv88jNkkgAYPp?p=preview

Basically I extended the solution from CodeZilla above using a scope variable in an Array.

```
$scope.func = [];
```

The name of the function to be called is then passed in the directive attribute functionname.

```
<div mydir name="dir1" functionname="sayhello1">Directive dir1</div>
```

The functions to be called from the directive are then added to the controller:

```
$scope.callDir1 = function (){
    $scope.func['sayhello1']();
}

$scope.callDir2 = function (){
    $scope.func['sayhello2']();
}
```

In the directive itself, we use compile to create the function within the directive that will be called from the controller.

```
app.directive('mydir', function () {
    return {
    scope: true,
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.$parent.func[iAttrs.functionname] = function (){
                alert("update something in " + iAttrs.name);
            }

        }
    }
}
});
```

Alternatively, you could use the link function - it works the same:

```
app.directive('mydir', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$parent.func[attrs.functionname] = function () {
                console.debug("update something in " + attrs.name);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That's it.